# Cannot load tflite model, Did not get operators or tensors in subgraph 1

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-lite, quantization

I have converted a tf model to tflite, and applied quantization in the process, but I cannot load it. The error was raised when I try to do `interpreter = tf.lite.Interpreter(tflite_model_path)`, the error message was:

```
ValueError: Did not get operators or tensors in subgraph 1.
```

Also during quantization, I got lots of these INFO messages for every dense layer in my model:

```
2021-09-06 04:38:40.879693: I tensorflow/lite/tools/optimize/quantize_weights.cc:217] Skipping quantization of tensor bert_token_clssfification/classifier/Tensordot/Shape that is not type float.
```

These messages confuse me greatly, because I'm sure those weights are of type float32. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the cause in my case. It was because I have dropout layers in my model, and I'm using an input tf.bool tensor to explicitly control the training/inference mode of the dropouts layers. Dropout is not currently supported in tflite, and because I'm explicitly controlling the dropout behaviour, the tflite conversion cannot remove the dropout operations.

The correct way to use dropout is to pass the `training` kwarg during model invocation: `out = model(input_batch, training=True)`.